# pandas: groupby 1 column, sum another, and get rid of duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this has been asked & answered before but I'm probably phrasing my question wrong.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
  article day views
0  729910  13   162
1  729910  14   283
2  730855  13     1
3  731449  13     2
```

I want to have a single row per value in article, and to have a `views`/`total_views` column that sums `views` number for each occurrence of the article in the row.

So the output should be this (`day` doesn't matter for me here):

```
  article  views
0  729910  445 (162 + 283)
1  730855  1
2  731449  2
```

The closest I got is:

```
parsed_report_df.groupby(['article', 'day'])['views'].sum()
```

Which yields:

```
article  day
729910   13     162
         14     283
730855   13       1
731449   13       2
735682   12       1
```

but I just need the same for `views` every different `day` for each `article`.

Comment: @jezrael doesn't work but thanks for trying.

Comment: @jezrael - sorry, fixed.

Comment: doesn't work. gives an obscene number for article `729910`.

Comment: that prints `object`. I thought the conversion was made automatically..?

Comment: @jezrael - this worked, thanks! can you add as an answer? would be nice to know how this specific group-by expression works.

Comment: Yes. That’s the one that’s working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert column to floats or integers first by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then aggregate `sum` by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

Solution working with `Series` - in `groupby` is also used `Series` - `article` column:

```
 df = (parsed_report_df['views'].astype(float)
                                .groupby(parsed_report_df['article']).sum()
                                .reset_index())
print (df)
  article  views
0  729910  445.0
1  730855    1.0
2  731449    2.0
```

Another solution with assign back converted valuse of column `views`:

```
parsed_report_df['views'] = parsed_report_df['views'].astype(float)
df = parsed_report_df.groupby('article', as_index=False)['views'].sum()
print (df)
  article  views
0  729910  445.0
1  730855    1.0
2  731449    2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted. Why do I need `as_index` or `reset_index` in these cases?

Comment: @zerohedge - `as_index=False` is used for return `DataFrame` - convert index values to columns. But  fun is it not working always, always working `.reset_imdex()` what do same.

Comment: but it also returns a DataFrame even if `as_index` is `true`? or does it return something else?

Comment: It return `Series`, if `as_index=True` - it is default value, so should be omited.

Answer (score 2):

Remove extra column, groupby, sum and reset_index should get you the output

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[729910, 13, 162],[729910, 14, 283],[730855,13,1],[731449, 13,2]], columns=['article','day', 'views'])

>>> df
   article  day  views
0   729910   13    162
1   729910   14    283
2   730855   13      1
3   731449   13      2

>>> df[['article','views']].groupby('article').sum().reset_index()

   article  views
0   729910    445
1   730855      1
2   731449      2
```